# Can “sozusagen” be translated as “sort of”?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice

> Ich lerne schon seit fast 15 Jahren Deutsch, jedoch mache ich immer noch Fehler, also halte ich mich für Anfänger, ***sozusagen***.

Can it also be substituted by ***so ähnlich***?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they have a slightly different meaning.

1. **sozusagen**: so to speak, in a manner of speaking
2. **so ähnlich**: similar to sth.

> Ich lerne schon seit fast 15 Jahren Deutsch, jedoch mache ich immer noch Fehler, also halte ich mich sozusagen für einen Anfänger.

Which is fine, but the following sounds better:

> Obwohl ich schon seit fast 15 Jahren Deutsch lerne, mache ich noch immer Fehler. Ich halte mich sozusagen für einen Anfänger.

And in case you want to use **so ähnlich**, you can go for: (sounds really submissive)

> ...Da ich jedoch noch immer Fehler mache, ist mein Deutsch so ähnlich wie das eines Anfängers.